# Jest Testing Error when using @okta/okta-auth-js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, okta, okta-api

I have a React application that is providing a third party SSO via Okta, so making use of the `@okta/okta-auth-js` package.

Have an authentication file that defines an instance of `OktaAuth` and passes the setup config:

```js
import OktaAuth, { OktaAuthOptions } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';

const oktaConfig: OktaAuthOptions = {
  issuer: `issuer_val_here`,
  ...etc,
};

const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);
```

All running fine in app, but when it comes to running jest tests of components that make use of this authentication file in any way I'm getting the immediate error:

```
TypeError: _oktaAuthJs.default is not a constructor

      28 | };
      29 |
    > 30 | const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);
         |                  ^
```

I've tried to mock this and set it up so many different ways from git threads and forum posts, I've tried:

```json
   "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@okta/okta-auth-js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@okta/okta-auth-js/dist/okta-auth-js.min.js"
    }
```

in the `package.json`

I've tried all of the different combinations of `jest.mock` and mocking in `setupTests.js` that I can think of and I'm still getting this error with no change

Has anyone dealt with this before and got it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your import should be:

```js
import { OktaAuth, OktaAuthOptions } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
```

instead of

```js
import OktaAuth, { OktaAuthOptions } from '@okta/okta-auth-js';
```